# VBA Excel, loop through 2 columns if when same value then calculate value from another colum

Tags: excel, vba, loops, duplicates

Hay I have the following problem and need help:

I have this table

A-----------B----------C-----------Start date---End date

Phase1.1--Phase1----Analyst-----1/1/2018------1/3/2019

Phase1.1--Phase1----Analyst-----1/2/2018------1/4/2020

Phase1.1--Phase1----Analyst-----1/3/2018------1/5/2019

Phase1.1--Phase1----Manager-----1/2/2018------1/7/2019

Phase1.1--Phase1----Manager-----1/1/2018------1/5/2019

Phase1.1--Phase2----Analyst-----1/1/2018------1/3/2019

……..

I want to loop through this table and check if column B values are same (Duplicate) the move to column C and for the same values in column C calculate the min for column "Start date" and the max for column "End date".
then write the rows in new excel sheet
So that I have for each entry in column C one row with start and end date depending on column B.
Moreover column A is always same and should be copied and not change. 
the result should be like that:

A-----B---------C-----------Start date------End date

Phase1.1---Phase1----Analyst----1/1/2018-----1/4/2020

Phase1.1---Phase1----Manager----1/1/2018-----1/7/2019

Phase1.1---Phase2----Analyst----1/1/2018-----1/3/2019

………..

this is how my [real data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpwuX.png)  looks like:

thanx for your support

Comment: Hi Youssef and welcome to StackOverflow.  You can improve your question quality if you edit it to lay out the table more intelligibly, and also let us know what you've tried so far to solve this yourself; we're here to help, not to do your work for you! ;)

Comment: why use VBA when you could use formulas for this?

Comment: @OurManinBananas or just a pivot-table

Comment: @Luuklag in the pivot table u can't see the start or end date if there are may values so u have always to collapse them to see the start date e.g.

Comment: Why do you believe that? You can make exactly the table you have as a desired result.

Comment: @ thanx a lot for the answer  but I already created pivot table and e.g. if I have 20 values for analyst in the pivot table the start date will not be visible u always need to uncollapse to see the values

Comment: @YoussefTouma You say you want to calculate the max end date for the same phase and title, but in your output you have `1/1/2018` to `1/5/2019` when there is a `1/4/2020` end date - why isn't that output `1/1/2018` and `1/4/2020`?

Comment: @YoussefTouma Also why is column A the number 4 for Phase 1 - Manager instead of the number 5? You need to be very specific for *how* you're getting your expected outcome, or it's impossible for us to draw the logic and help you. I've voted to close this question as "unclear what you're asking", because without clarification this cannot be solved.

Comment: Sorry it was mistyping it should be 1/4/2020 @dwirony

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it via VBA.

```
Sub rowLoop()
Dim lRow As Long, lRow2 As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim startDate As String, endDate As String

Set ws1 = Sheets("Data") 'set this to be the worksheet with data
Set ws2 = Sheets("Results") 'set this to the worksheet you want the results to go

lRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find last used row

ws2.Range("B2:C" & lRow).Value = ws1.Range("B2:C" & lRow).Value 'copy over Column B values
ws2.Range("$B$2:$C$" & lRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo 'remove duplicates


lRow2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'find last used row
For i = 2 To lRow2 'loop through rows to determin start and end date
    ws2.Range("A" & i).Value = i - 1

    For j = 2 To lRow
        If ws2.Range("B" & i).Value = ws1.Range("B" & j).Value And ws2.Range("C" & i).Value = ws1.Range("C" & j).Value Then
            If startDate = "" Then
                startDate = ws1.Range("D" & j).Value
            Else
                If ws1.Range("D" & j).Value < startDate Then
                    startDate = ws1.Range("D" & j).Value
                End If
            End If

            If endDate = "" Then
                endDate = ws1.Range("E" & j).Value
            Else
                If ws1.Range("E" & j).Value > endDate Then
                    endDate = ws1.Range("E" & j).Value
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next j
    ws2.Range("D" & i).Value = startDate
    ws2.Range("E" & i).Value = endDate
    startDate = ""
    endDate = ""
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
Hay thanx a lot for your answer I was testing it now there is a small problem: 
in the new sheet the column B and C are correctly copied but the start and end date are not correct. 
the mistake is in the start date and the end date in the new sheet the value is a random one from the range e.g. for analyst is the one in the middle but not the min or the max one.. Do you have an Idea why?

Comment: The code works perfectly for me.  It may be because of the formatting on either sheet.  You can step through the code and see how the date is changing to see where it's not capturing the correct date

Comment: Without seeing your actually data I can't say for sure.  But the example data you gave in the question works with this code.

Comment: Actually, one idea is to place a break after the lRow is calculated.  Check to see if it's being set to your actual last row.  It may be that the code isn't going to the end of the sheet because of some blanks in the rows

Comment: how can I send you my data? @VBA_SQL_Programmer

Comment: The code did not work for me - only produced 2 lines on the Results worksheet, and it doesn't match the original output outlined above... hm.